# Javascript audio 'buffer/lags' on first time playing through?

Tags: javascript, audio, meteor, lag

I've been developing an application using MeteorJS, and basically what it does is play corresponding sound files upon clicking a play button. It uses Timeout to set intervals that it plays, because it's a music application that plays chords.

I create sound objects in an array (see example) and play them when need be. They are created in the .js file, not in any function or anything, so I assume it occurs upon  first loading the document?

However, the first time it plays the files, sometimes it pauses and throws the timing off, but I've noticed that it doesn't lag much or at all once the audio has played at least once. If I refresh the page, it will again lag the first time and then be fine.

Is this a loading issue? Cache issue? I'm not super well-versed on how exactly Audio is loaded and handled through js. Would it be better to try to use a library and/or different sound formatting? Any feedback is appreciated, because the problem is quite noticeable and important to try and fix because it's an audio-dependent application by nature.

Code to set up the chords (just first one in array as the example) not in a function, so supposedly upon startup this is executed:

```
var standardChord = [];
standardChord[0] = new Audio('/A.flac');
```

And when such a chord is played:

```
if (!standardChord[0].ended) {
        standardChord[0].currentTime = 0;
}
standardChord[0].play();
```

Thank you!
(I'm using google chrome)

Comment: Please add some code example that describes the core problem. Otherwise it's very hard to reproduce your issue. Since this is closely related to a Webstandard, please also add which browser(s) and versions you use where the issue is involved.

Comment: I have added more useful information, hopefully someone has an idea, or at least advice.